# How to make a "link" from CheckboxlistTile to another page on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm making a Terms and Conditions agreement and I want this sentence to be highlighted and clickable, when clicked it should take the user to another page in the app where they can read the agreement. I'm having trouble creating something that's both clickable and highlighted.

Here is my code:

````
 CheckboxListTile(
        value: checkboxValue,
      onChanged: (val) {
        if (checkboxValue == false) {
          setState(() {
            checkboxValue = true;
          });
        } else if (checkboxValue == true) {
          setState(() {
            checkboxValue = false;
          });
        }
      },
      subtitle: !checkboxValue
          ? Text(
              'Required.',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            )
          : null,
      title: new Text(
        'I agree to the Terms and Conditions.',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
      ),
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      activeColor: Colors.green,
    ),
    ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your Text widget with a `GestureDetector()`. See code below

```
CheckboxListTile(
                value: checkboxValue,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    checkboxValue = !checkboxValue;
                  });
                },
                subtitle: !checkboxValue
                    ? Text(
                  'Required.',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                )
                    : null,
                title: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context){
                          return Page();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'I agree to the Terms and Conditions.',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                  ),
                ),
                controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                activeColor: Colors.green,
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text with `Inkwell` or `GestureDetector`.

Sample code here:

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () { },
            child: Text(
              "Sample Text",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, color: Colors.blue
              ),
            ),
          )
```